# go-pg how to select also entity from related table?

Tags: go, go-pg

```
type Book struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"book" json:"-"`
    Id        int      `pg:"id,pk" json:"id"`
    Author    int      `pg:"author_id,notnull" json:"-"`
    Author    *Author  `pg:"fk:author_id" json:"author,omitempty"`
}
```

I want select book and author in one query.

If I try this:

```
var r []model.Book
_, err := dao.FusedDb.Query(&r, `SELECT * FROM book b INNER JOIN author a on a.id = b.author_id`)
```

I get an error

> pg: can't find column=name in model=Book (try discard_unknown_columns)

Comment: You probably have to explicitly select the columns you want or it will grab all including the ones in the join.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down a piece of code that I always use when I've to deal with this scenario. First, let me show the code and then I'll comment on the relevant parts:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string
    Description string
    AuthorID    uint
    Author      Author
}

type Author struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Books     []Book
}

type Result struct {
    BookId    int
    AuthorId  int
    Title     string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

func main() {
    conn, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    // query
    var result []Result
    rows, err := conn.Query("select b.id, a.id, b.title, a.first_name, a.last_name from authors a inner join books b on a.id = b.author_id")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var record Result
        if err := rows.Scan(&record.BookId, &record.AuthorId, &record.Title, &record.FirstName, &record.LastName); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        result = append(result, record)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", result)
}
```

##### Structs definition

The `Book` and `Author` structs represent the tables defined in my database. `Result` is used to hold the fetched records through the query specified below.

##### The query

The query is pretty straightforward. We only used the method `Query` on the SQL client opened at the beginning of the `main` function. Then, we've to defer a call to the method `Close` on the `rows` variable to clean up.

##### Scanning

The `for` makes sure that we scan all of the rows retrieved with the `Query` method. To understand if there are other rows to fetch we use the method `Next` that returns a bool value indicating whether or not there are other rows to scan.
In the body of the `for` we declare a loop-scoped variable to hold the current record. Thanks to the `Scan` method we'll be able to assign each column to the relative field of the struct.
Lastly, we've to check for any error by invoking the method `Err` on the `rows` variable and handle it.
Let me know if this clarifies your question, thanks!